# HP Fortify scan using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, fortify, fortify-source

I am using the configuration below in build.gradle for running HP Fortify scan:

```
// Fortify configuration
configurations {
  fortify { extendsFrom compile }
}

// pull in the fortify libs for the new configuration
dependencies {
  fortify 'com.fortify:sourceanalyzer:3.90'
}

task fortifyReport(dependsOn: compileJava) << {
  ant.properties['build.compiler']='com.fortify.dev.ant.SCACompiler'
  ant.typedef(name: 'sca', classname: 'com.fortify.dev.ant.SourceanalyzerTask', classpath: configurations.fortify.asPath)
  ant.sca(jdk:"1.7",
    debug:true ,
    verbose:true ,
    failonerror:true ,
    scan:true ,
    logFile:file("$buildDir/reports/fortify/Fortify.log"),
    resultsFile:file("$buildDir/reports/fortify/${project.name}.fpr")
  ){
    fileset(dir:'src/main') {
      include(name:'**/*.java')
    }
  }
}
```

But when executing I am getting the below:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fortifyReport'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration157'.
> Could not find com.fortify:sourceanalyzer:3.90.
```

I am not able to find the sourceanalyzer:3.90 plugin on the internet. Please advise on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

As of SCA 16.20, Gradle integration is now supported.

From the official documentation [HPE Security Fortify Static Code Analyzer User Guide](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-software-security-center/) - Chapter 13: Build Integration

**Gradle Integration**

You can translate projects that are built with Gradle without requiring any modification of the `build.gradle` file. When the build runs, Fortify Static Code Analyzer translates the source files as they are compiled. See the HPE Security Fortify Software System Requirements document for platforms and languages supported specifically for Gradle integration. Any files in the project that are use unsupported languages for Gradle integration are not translated (with no error reporting). These files are therefore not analyzed and any existing potential vulnerabilities can go undetected.

To integrate Fortify Static Code Analyzer into your Gradle build, make sure that the `sourceanalyzer` executable is on the system PATH. Prepend the Gradle command line with the `sourceanalyzer` command as follows:

```
sourceanalyzer -b <build_id> <sca_options> gradle [<gradle_options>] <gradle tasks>
```

For example:

```
sourceanalyzer -b buildxyz gradle clean build
sourceanalyzer -b buildxyz gradle --info assemble
```

**Note:** If you use the Fortify Static Code Analyzer `-verbose` option, then you must also include the `-gradle` option. For example:

```
sourceanalyzer -b buildxyz -gradle -verbose gradle assemble
```

Comment: How to get the sourceanalyser to system PATH? I tried setting up the path from task but it failed